# Is looping a socket input stream continuously considered as polling?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, client-server

I'm creating a chat app using basic java socket programming. So far I have completed the text chat part. Now I want to implement a push notification feature in it. Currently I am looping infinitely on client and server socket input stream to receive and send the text. Something like this

```
        BufferedReader serverIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
        String line = serverIn.readLine();
        while(true) {
            if(line!=null)
            System.out.println(line);
            line = serverIn.readLine();
        }
```

Is this considered as polling or is this normal way to use sockets ? If this is okay then how is implementing push notifications any different than what I have currently done.

Since I'm checking input stream continuously so whenever server will send data on it's output stream I will receive it on my input stream. If it is chat text I'll display it in chat window if it is a notification I'll display it in notification window.

Am I correct or my concept of push notification is vague and they are implemented any differently using sockets ?

Comment: This is the normal way to use sockets, and it is considered to be blocking I/O, not polling. But it doesn't work the way you seem to think. `readLine()` will only return null at end of stream, which only happens on a socket when the peer closes the connection. Otherwise it will block while no line is available, and return a complete line without the terminator. So if you get a null it is the end of that conversation, and you should close the socket and stop reading.

Comment: I see . Because I'm using a continuous tcp connection so that's why sending simple text and so called push notification is the same thing. Push notifications are a issue where there is not a continuous connection and they use polling or long polling to achieve that for example ajax. Am I right ?

Comment: Ajax is not a typical case. It isn't even correctly named. The 'A' is for 'asynchronous', but it isn't, it is just an XML request-response over HTTP, timed according to whatever the Javascript at the client determines. You could call that 'polling', or 'long polling' if long enough, but it's different from your question because there is a request as well as a response, so the 'poll' actually consists of sending a request. In the CPU/OS world, 'polling' means peeking at a register to see whether I/O is ready instead of depending on an interrupt, or more broadly speaking on the scheduler.